# Volume button : notification issue

Tags: ios, xcode, events, notifications, volume

I'm facing a strange bogue.
At launching, sometimes, my iOS app detect automatically an event on the volume button.

This bogue is really embarrassing because i have associated an action with the volume button, using the library [JPSVolumeButtonHandler](https://github.com/jpsim/JPSVolumeButtonHandler).

```
self.volumeButtonHandler = [JPSVolumeButtonHandler volumeButtonHandlerWithUpBlock:^{ 
     NSLog(@"Volume Up Button Pressed");
} downBlock:^{
     NSLog(@"Volume Down Button Pressed"); 
     [self snapStillImage];
}];
```

I've search in my app code, and i didn't found any line which could trigger this event.

How could i track this issue ?

Comment: check for / Start
[self.volumeButtonHandler startHandler:YES]; 
// Stop
[self.volumeButtonHandler stopHandler];

Comment: @AbhishekVerma I've checked JPSVolumeButtonHandler code. At initialization, it adjusts the volume to avoid a maximum or minimum state (because in this state it will couldn't detect any event on volume buttons).
But when adjusting, it's triggering by itself...